# Why is Mechanize returning "undefined method 'value=' for nil:NilClass" when trying to set a password?

Tags: ruby, scripting, mechanize

I wrote a script with Mechanize to scrape some links, which later I will write code to put into an Excel file.

For now I can't authenticate past the first page. I keep getting an undefined method `value= for nil:NilClass` when attempting to set the password in the form and haven't been able to find any information on it.

I don't even have the method `value=` in my code so I don't understand what is going on. The code runs fine for the username, but once I enter the password  and hit enter I get the error:

```
users.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `value=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):23:in `form_with'
    from formity_users.rb:7:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/codelitt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mechanize-2.7.1/lib/mechanize.rb:433:in `get'
    from formity_users.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

This is my users.rb script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new
a.get('https://www.example.com') do |page| 
  #Enter information into forms
  logged_in = page.form_with(:id => 'frmLogin') do |f| 
    puts "Username?"
    f.field_with(:name => "LoginCommand.EmailAddress").value = gets.chomp
    puts "Password?"
    f.field_with(:name => "Login.Password").value = gets.chomp
  end.click_button

  #Click drop down
  admin_page = logged_in.click.link_with(:text => /Admin/)
  #Click Users and enter user admin section
  user_admin = admin_page.click.link_with(:text => /Users/)

  #Scrape and print links for now
  user_admin.links.each do |link|
    text = link.text.strip
    next unless text.length > 0 
    puts text
  end 
end
```

Comment: I think your error is coming from `f.field_with(:name => "Login.Password")`, which seems to be `nil`. For username, I see that you have specified input name `LoginCommand.EmailAddress` and for password input name is `Login.Password`. I'd expect anybody who has written this markup to use consistent names. Maybe you should look that the underlying html to see you're using correct field names in your code.

Comment: nonocut is write ! `undefined method 'value=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` mean that `f.field_with(:name => "Login.Password")` is not find on the form `frmLogin` maybe the name of the field is false or maybe the field is out of the form

Comment: @nonocut You're right. I don't know how I missed it. I guess I was just staring at it for too long. Thank you.

Comment: @cz3ch You're both right. Thanks.

Comment: @codelitt I have added my comment as an answer. You can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is coming from

```
f.field_with(:name => "Login.Password")
```

which seems to be `nil`. For username, I see that you have specified input name `LoginCommand.EmailAddress` and for password input name is `Login.Password`.

I'd expect anybody who has written this markup to use consistent names. Maybe you should look that the underlying html to see you're using correct field names in your code.